# JSoup и аутентификация

Tags: java, jsoup, auth

После отправки данных - токена, логина и пароля переводит обратно на страницу авторизации. Хотя подобный код работает на ура с другими сайтами. Видимо есть какая то особенность о которой я не знаю. Может кто подскажет правильный подход к аутентификации через JSoup или где я ошибся.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.Map;
import org.jsoup.Connection.Method;
import org.jsoup.Connection.Response;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;

public class POA {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        HttpS.manageHttps(); // Для того чтобы пройти SSL

        String userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1667.0 Safari/537.36";



        // Получаю токен
        Response resp1 = Jsoup.connect("http://poavangard.com/auth/login").method(Method.GET).execute();    
        String token = resp1.parse().getElementsByTag("input").first().val().trim();
        System.out.println(token);


        // Упаковываю все в пост и отправляю
        Response resp2 = Jsoup.connect("http://poavangard.com/auth/login").referrer("https://poavangard.com/auth/login").userAgent(userAgent)               
                .data("_token", token, "email","test@poavangard.com", "password", "123456").cookies(resp1.cookies())
                .method(Method.POST).timeout(10000).execute();

        Map<String, String> common = resp2.cookies();
        System.out.println(resp2.cookies());
        System.out.println(resp2.parse().title() + " " + token);

        Document doc3 = Jsoup.connect("http://poavangard.com/profile").referrer("https://poavangard.com/auth/login").userAgent(userAgent).cookies(common).timeout(10000).get();
        System.out.println(doc3.title());
    }
}




/* Класс чтобы https не ругал */


import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;
import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager;

public class HttpS {
    public static void manageHttps() {

        TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[] { new X509TrustManager() {
            public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                return null;
            }

            public void checkClientTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
            }

            public void checkServerTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
            }
        } };

        try {
            SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
            sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());
            HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
}
```

Логин и пароль настоящие.